# Function is not a function and I don't know why

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the error `formValidationTest is not a function` in the console when I click the submit button that fires handleSubmit. I've been lost as to why I'm getting this message. Can someone please explain.

Path: `formValidationTest.js`

```
function formValidationTest(formData) {
  console.log('Test function');

  return true;
}

export default formValidationTest();
```

Path: `Signup.jsx`

import React from 'react';
import formValidationTest from './formValidation';

```
export default class Signup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: ''
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formErrors = formValidationTest('test');
  }

  render() {
    const { email } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <form className="needs-validation" noValidate>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            placeholder="Email"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <div className="invalid-feedback">{emailValidationMessage}</div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Sign up
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exporting the *result of* the `formValidationTest` function. Remove the parentheses:

```
export default formValidationTest;
```